# jersey - using an object with a list of super Classes containing Objects of several sub classes - sub classes are not unmarshalled correctly

Tags: list, jersey, subclass

I have a `QuestionsData` class that has a List of `QuestionData`. 
The `QuestionData` is an abstract class and has two implementations: `TextQuestionData` and `SelectionQuestionData`.

The problem is that after doing `clientResponse.getEntity`, I get the object with a list of `SelectionQuestionData` only, while I know that some of the questions are of type `TextQuestionData`.

I tried to add `@XmlSeeAlso`, but it did not help.
I also tried to change the order of elements in the `@XmlElementRefs` but that caused all the questions to be of type `TextQuestionData`.

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but the object I use in jersey is another Jaxb Object that has `QuestionsData` as a member

Here is the code:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "questions")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({SelectionQuestionData.class, TextQuestionData.class })
public class QuestionsData {

    @XmlElementRefs({@XmlElementRef(type = TextQuestionData.class), @XmlElementRef(type = SelectionQuestionData.class)})
    private List<QuestionData> questions;

    private QuestionsData() {}

    public QuestionsData(List<QuestionData> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "question")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TextQuestionData extends QuestionData {

    @XmlElement
    private String someString;

    public TextQuestionData() {}
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "question")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SelectionQuestionData extends QuestionData {

    @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "option")})
    private List<String> options;

    public  SelectionQuestionData() {}
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. What does your abstract `QuestionData` class look like? Are you certain that there are instances of both implementing classes in the returned data?

Comment: exactly the same as the rest of them , but with more fields and no root element defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this use case the element name is used to determine which subclass (mapped with `@XmlRootElement`) should be instantiated during unmarshalling.  Since you mapped both subclasses to `question` the JAXB (JSR-222) implementation can not determine the correct one to unmarshal.  You will need to map them to different root elements.

**TextQuestionData**

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "textQuestion")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TextQuestionData extends QuestionData {

    @XmlElement
    private String someString;

    public TextQuestionData() {}
}
```

**SelectionQuestionData**

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "selectionQuestion")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SelectionQuestionData extends QuestionData {

    @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "option")})
    private List<String> options;

    public  SelectionQuestionData() {}
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: is there no way to workaround it? this is a code I cannot change, as it will break the api to customers.

Comment: @Elyran - You could use an `XmlAdapter` to map the inheritance relationship:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Comment: I already tried that, the problem is that the adapter gives me the already wrong-created object that does not have the required data that exists in the second implementation: the SelectionQuestionData will no have the someString data.

Comment: @Elyran - Check out the `XmlAdapter` example again.  The adapted object contains the properties of both classes.  Then based on what is populated you choose (in the adapter) which subclass to build.